# Error en JSON en la posición 2

Tags: json

Me da este error por consola.

```
VM96637:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Le doy y me muestra el siguiente array en VM96637:

`32,Dispon,Dispon,2019-07-15,2019-07-29,1,08:00:00,10:00:00,none,#C0C1FF`

Comment: tu cadena de texto no es un JSON valido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes convertir primero tu cadena a `JSON` de esta forma

```
const cadena = '32,Dispon,Dispon,2019-07-15,2019-07-29,1,08:00:00,10:00:00,none,#C0C1FF';
const cadenaJson = JSON.stringify(cadena);
```

Para obtener los datos haces lo siguiente

```
const CadenaConvertida = JSON.Parse(cadenaJson);
```

Cuando llames a `CadenaConvertida` podras acceder a las posisiones;

```js
const cadena = '32,Dispon,Dispon,2019-07-15,2019-07-29,1,08:00:00,10:00:00,none,#C0C1FF';
const cadenaJson = JSON.stringify(cadena);
console.log('cadena Json: ' +cadenaJson)
const CadenaConvertida = JSON.parse(cadenaJson);
console.log('cadena Parse: ' + CadenaConvertida);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otra opcion es crear un array y convertirlo en json

```js
 const cadena = '32,Dispon,Dispon,2019-07-15,2019-07-29,1,08:00:00,10:00:00,none,#C0C1FF';
 
 const arrayDeCadenas = cadena.split(',');
 
 console.log(arrayDeCadenas)
 
 const JsonCadena = JSON.stringify(arrayDeCadenas)
 
 console.log(JsonCadena)
 
 const JSONParse = JSON.parse(JsonCadena)
 
 console.log(JSONParse)
 
 console.log(JSONParse[3])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona a la perfección